¿Como puedo filtrar columnas en una tabla dentro de power bi?
estoy haciendo un proyecto en Power Bi, el cual está en el servicio report server de power bi, el Bi contiene una tabla y está alimentada mediante una consulta direct query a una base de datos oracle, la tabla se puede exportar a excel, el problema es que los usuarios no necesitan exportar todas las columnas, ya que son más de 100, por lo que necesito permitir que los usuarios exporten solo las columnas que ellos decidan.
